# What is the right term for "I have some issues new users usually have when doing something new"

Tags: word-choice

When trying a new product / service, and having some "initial road bumps" when getting started, is there a term that describes this situation?

E.g. if I write to a support person - "Hi, I'm having some _______ when trying to ..."

I am looking for something other than "Difficulty", "Issues", "Problems", "Errors" and more of a "Stuff you usually get when trying something new", or even more accurately "Common issues every new product usually has and are *not* always the fault of the user".

e.g. I don't know if it is my fault or the new product has issues.

Is there a phrase / idiom / wording that conveys that?

Comment: Teething troubles.

Answer (score 3):

In computing, "teething issues" or "teething trouble" is commonly used in this context. Also, "gotchas" is often heard, for common mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

"Bugs" or "glitches" would work, although  both are pretty informal. For example, "This product works well, but there are a few bugs that need to be worked out," or "I started using this product and I ran into a few glitches."

Comment: I agree with "glitches" because it could be the user's glitch or a product glitch - but "bug" usually lays blame on the product - which it seems the OP is not ready to concede at such as early stage.

Comment: True. But "bugs" would apply to his request for a word that means "common issues every new product usually has and are _not_ always the fault of the user." Bugs would not be the fault of the user, while glitches, as you said, could be the fault of the user or of the product.